# Use single url to access multiple backbase pages

Tags: backbase

Is it possible to create single url to access all backbase pages?
For instance I have two pages /portal/xyz/abc and /portal/xyz1/abc1. I want to access them via single url in web browser.

Comment: I don't quite follow? Do you want to show two pages at the same time? As in, you would show them as one page?

Comment: Suppose I have two pages. Backbase internally create their url - contextroot/portalname/pagename. I want only one name gets displayed in url bar of browser like abc.com while navigating from 1 page to another.

Comment: Basically the user should only be able to see domain name and not the urls of the pages he is navigating. For instance if u will login to a bank's Netbanking, you would only see ICICI.com in url and not the urls of the individual pages. Since we are using backbase I am incompetent in doing this.

Comment: But then you would completely break the idea behind URLs? How will they for example be able to bookmark the page if you don't provide a url?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with "LauncherDeckContainer". 
Check Backbase documents for more information. The idea    is to create only one page having a container, and then create multiple child panel. Each panel will have own widgets.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll read the documentation to see how it works.